# Clawsmail 4.1: reason for lag when clicking on emails

Tags: flatpak, lag, claws-mail

- Clawsmail 4.1.1 (flatpak) (pop3 mailboxes)
- GTK 3.24.37 / GLib 2.72.4
- Locale: en_AU.UTF-8 (charset: UTF-8)
- Operating System: Linux 6.2.6-76060206-generic (x86_64)

After receiving emails from pop server, about a 2-second lag occurs when I click on the email, before I can read the emails. Occurs for new and old emails, and occurs when scrolling through the folders and emails.

Might anybody have any ideas why the lag occurs?